# Product Alerts and Backorders together

Tags: magento-1.8, product

on **stock level = zero** a product should offer the following:

i) **Allow backorders**, i.e. allow user to order even though stock is zero; and

ii) **show the "Alert me when this product is back in stock" link.**

I think it makes sense to allow those customers who want to pay money in advance to do so, and to allow the others who just want an alert to do so too.

However I've found that **Magento only allows you to have one or the other**.

Any help appreciated!